# WSDL import issue with Delphi

Tags: web-services, delphi, wsdl

I am trying to use the Reuters webservice and getting errors when I build a sample program to access the webservice. I am using Delphi 2010 and the wsdl is located at  https://hosted.datascopeapi.reuters.com/datascopeapi/v1/extractionservice.asmx?wsdl.

After importing the WSDL the Interface is defined as:

```
     ExtractionService = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{CD3DF44F-6D8E-C594-D58C-6A258701D678}']

    // Headers: EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetVersion: VersionInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetInstrumentSearchTypes: ArrayOfInstrumentSearchTypeInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetInstrumentExtractionTypes: ArrayOfInstrumentExtractionTypeInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetLegalEntityExtractionTypes: ArrayOfLegalEntityExtractionTypeInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetCounterpartyExtractionTypes: ArrayOfCounterpartyExtractionTypeInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetInstrumentIdentifierTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetLegalEntityIdentifierTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetCounterpartyIdentifierTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetBondScheduleTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetCoraxEvents: ArrayOfCoraxEventInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetCoraxShareTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetInstrumentTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetSymbolCrossReferenceTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetFuturesAndOptionsTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetFuturesAndOptionsPutCallTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetFuturesAndOptionsExerciseStylesTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetFuturesAndOptionsCurrencyTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetFuturesAndOptionsExchangeTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetFuturesAndOptionsStatusTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetEquitiesAssetCategoryTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetEquitiesCurrencyTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetEquitiesDomicileTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetEquitiesExchangeTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetEquitiesFairValueIndicatorTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetEquitiesGicsIndustryTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetEquitiesInstrumentSubTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetEquitiesStatusTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetGovCorpCurrencyTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetGovCorpCountryTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetGovCorpIndustryTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetGovCorpContributorTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetGovCorpAssetStatusTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetGovCorpMoodyTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetGovCorpStandardPoorsTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetGovCorpSubGroupTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetGovCorpSubGroupExtTypes: ArrayOfValueInfoSubvalue; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetUSMunicipalsAssetStatusTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetUSMunicipalsMoodyTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetUSMunicipalsStandardPoorsTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetUSMunicipalsStateTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetTimeseriesLookbackPeriodTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetEstimateTypes: ArrayOfEstimateTypeInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetEstimateDeltaDaysValues: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetEstimateHistoricalRelativeSemiAnnualValues: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetEstimateHistoricalRelativeQuarterValues: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetEstimateHistoricalRelativeFiscalYearValues: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetEstimateFutureRelativeSemiAnnualValues: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetEstimateFutureRelativeQuarterValues: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetEstimateFutureRelativeFiscalYearValues: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetEstimateCompanyTypeValues: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetCmoAbsAssetStatusTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetCmoAbsSubGroupTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetCmoAbsSubGroupExtTypes: ArrayOfValueInfoSubvalue; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetMbsAgencyTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetMbsAmortizationTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetMbsAssetStatusTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetMbsPoolTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetMbsSecurityGroupTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetMbsSettleMonthTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetFundAllocationTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetFundsCurrencyTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetFundsDomicileTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  GetComparisonOperators: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: EjvServerHeader:pIn
    function  GetNewsAnalyticsSourceValues: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: EjvServerHeader:pIn
    function  GetNewsAnalyticsNoveltyFields: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: EjvServerHeader:pIn
    function  GetNewsAnalyticsNoveltyOperators: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: EjvServerHeader:pIn
    function  GetNewsAnalyticsRelevanceOperators: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: EjvServerHeader:pIn
    function  GetNewsAnalyticsSentimentValues: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: EjvServerHeader:pIn
    function  GetNewsAnalyticsTopicCodes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: EjvServerHeader:pIn
    function  GetNewsItemsTopicCodes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: EjvServerHeader:pIn
    function  GetNewsItemsSourceValues: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: EjvServerHeader:pIn
    function  GetRatingsSourceValues: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: EjvServerHeader:pIn
    function  GetNewsItemsLanguages: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: EjvServerHeader:pIn
    function  GetPremiumPricingTypes: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;
    function  GetIssuerAssetClasses: ArrayOfValueInfo; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  Define(const request: DataDictionaryRequest): DataDictionaryResponse; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  ValidateInstruments(const request: InstrumentValidationRequest): InstrumentValidationResponse; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  ValidateLegalEntities(const request: LegalEntityValidationRequest): LegalEntityValidationResponse; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  ValidateCounterparties(const request: CounterpartyValidationRequest): CounterpartyValidationResponse; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  SearchInstruments(const request: InstrumentSearchRequest): InstrumentSearchResponse; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  SearchLegalEntities(const request: LegalEntitySearchRequest): LegalEntitySearchResponse; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  SearchCounterparties(const request: CounterpartySearchRequest): CounterpartySearchResponse; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  Extract(const request: ExtractionRequest): ExtractionResponse; stdcall;

    // Headers: CredentialsHeader:pInOut, EjvServerHeader:pIn, OperationInfoHeader:pOut
    function  ReportUsage(const request: UsageRequest): UsageResponse; stdcall;
  end;
```

The initialization defined below, seems to be defined correctly but I get an error whenever it references the ExtractionService  as if the import has not defined the IInvokable interface correctly but I cant see what is not correct. The first error shows (E2089 Invalid typecast) on the registerinterface line against the Typeinfo(ExtractionService) and additional errors are displayed whenever the ExtractionService is referenced.

```
initialization
  InvRegistry.RegisterInterface(TypeInfo(ExtractionService), 'http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/', 'UTF-8');
  InvRegistry.RegisterAllSOAPActions(TypeInfo(ExtractionService), '|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetVersion'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetInstrumentSearchTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetInstrumentExtractionTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetLegalEntityExtractionTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetCounterpartyExtractionTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetInstrumentIdentifierTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetLegalEntityIdentifierTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetCounterpartyIdentifierTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetBondScheduleTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetCoraxEvents'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetCoraxShareTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetInstrumentTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetSymbolCrossReferenceTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetFuturesAndOptionsTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetFuturesAndOptionsPutCallTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetFuturesAndOptionsExerciseStylesTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetFuturesAndOptionsCurrencyTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetFuturesAndOptionsExchangeTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetFuturesAndOptionsStatusTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetEquitiesAssetCategoryTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetEquitesCurrencyTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetEquitesDomicileTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetEquitesExchangeTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetEquitesFairValueIndicatorTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetEquitesGicsIndustryTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetEquitesInstrumentSubTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetEquitesStatusTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetGovCorpCurrencyTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetGovCorpCountryTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetGovCorpIndustryTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetGovCorpContributorTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetGovCorpAssetStatusTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetGovCorpMoodyTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetGovCorpStandardPoorsTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetGovCorpSubGroupTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetGovCorpSubGroupExtTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetUSMunicipalsAssetStatusTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetUSMunicipalsMoodyTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetUSMunicipalsStandardPoorsTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetUSMunicipalsStateTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetTimeseriesLookbackPeriodTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetEstimateTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetEstimateDeltaDaysValues'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetEstimateHistoricalRelativeSemiAnnualValues'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetEstimateHistoricalRelativeQuarterValues'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetEstimateHistoricalRelativeFiscalYearValues'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetEstimateFutureRelativeSemiAnnualValues'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetEstimateFutureRelativeQuarterValues'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetEstimateFutureRelativeFiscalYearValues'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetEstimateCompanyTypeValues'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetCmoAbsAssetStatusTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetCmoAbsSubGroupTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetCmoAbsSubGroupExtTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetMbsAgencyTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetMbsAmortizationTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetMbsAssetStatusTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetMbsPoolTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetMbsSecurityGroupTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetMbsSettleMonthTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetFundAllocationTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetFundsCurrencyTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetFundsDomicileTypes'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/GetComparisonOperators'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/Define'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/ValidateInstruments'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/ValidateLegalEntities'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/ValidateCounterparties'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/SearchInstruments'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/SearchLegalEntities'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/SearchCounterparties'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/Extract'
                                                                 +'|http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/ReportUsage'
                                                                 );
  InvRegistry.RegisterInvokeOptions(TypeInfo(ExtractionService), ioDocument);
  InvRegistry.RegisterInvokeOptions(TypeInfo(ExtractionService), ioSOAP12);
  InvRegistry.RegisterHeaderClass(TypeInfo(ExtractionService), EjvServerHeader2, 'EjvServerHeader', 'http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/');
  InvRegistry.RegisterHeaderClass(TypeInfo(ExtractionService), OperationInfoHeader2, 'OperationInfoHeader', 'http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/');
  InvRegistry.RegisterHeaderClass(TypeInfo(ExtractionService), CredentialsHeader2, 'CredentialsHeader', 'http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeInfo is a function in [System unit](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/System.TypeInfo).

i've checked my application that use wsdl, the **TypeInfo** is used from System unit as a function. Please try refactoring the **TypeInfo** class that was generated by Delphi in your code or add System unit name to all **TypeInfo** castings to make it a function from System unit.

```
InvRegistry.RegisterInterface(TypeInfo(ExtractionService), 'http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/', 'UTF-8');
```

change it like this.

```
InvRegistry.RegisterInterface(System.TypeInfo(ExtractionService), 'http://reuters.com/datascopeselect/ExtractionService/v1/', 'UTF-8');
```

I've tried second way and successfuly compiled.